# Magento, see if back-end user is online?

Tags: magento, backend

I have a Magento website.
There is admin user, thats me, and a other user.
How can I see if the other user is logged in (back-end) ?

#### EDIT

Thanks to Sandeep I now have this:

```
<?php   
    $session = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session');
    $userDetails = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session'); 
     // Get data from the session $userID = 
    $userDetails->getUser()->getUserId(); 
     // Get user ID $userID = 
    $userDetails->getUser()->getEmail();

    // Use the 'admin/session' object to check loggedIn status
    if ( $session->isLoggedIn() ) {
        echo "Ingelogd";
    } else {
        echo "Niet ingelogt";
    }
?>
```

Comment: This code will show if you are logged in, not that the other user is logged in! Are you sure this is your answer?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session');

// Use the 'admin/session' object to check loggedIn status
if ( $session->isLoggedIn() ) {
   echo "logged in";
} else {
   echo "not logged in";
}
```